# Shape Contour modelling

Tags: modeling

I'm practising with this sphere object, and as seen in the example I have chosen a selection of faces, which I then merge by (faces), but the merged faces doing retain the sphere contour, but rather merge to a flat mesh surface. Is there a way to merge these faces but the same time the sphere retains its shape without the deformation.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Not really, as far as I know. You've eliminated all the enclosed vertices of the inner faces, which are necessary to maintain the original geometry. Perhaps you should explain what you're trying to achieve with this merge so that people can offer alternative solutions.

Comment: I wasn't trying to achieve anything in particular, just experimenting with Blender because I'm a novice user. So wanted to see out of curiosity if there was a correct way of getting a sphere with a whole by maintaining the curve.

Comment: Faces don't bend. Curvature is created by adding enough vertices to avoid non-planar geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. 
The deformation of the mesh is created by the different positions of each vertex. If you delete vertices, you will lose information thus losing the original shape.

There is no way for the software to know where you would want the face to bend, and as a matter of fact the preferred way to tell that to the software is to add vertices and move them accordingly.